# Pre-install driver on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, driver, inno-setup

I am trying to create an installer (using Inno Setup) that will pre-install a USB driver for an LCD HMI.  I have the drivers from the manufacturer (they appear to be signed).  However, no matter what I do, Windows will first detect the driver as a "Gadget Serial v2.4" device, then immediately go to "Windows Update" and downloads a "PNX Bulk Device" driver.

This driver does not work with the HMI.  I have to then manually open up Device Manager, find the "PNX Bulk Device", go to "Update Driver Software"..."Browse My Computer", "Have Disk", etc.

This is a very arduous process and may be overwhelming for an inexperienced user.

Is there anyway to automate the process, such that if the package is installed before the USB device is plugged in, then the driver will be in place, and Windows will use the correct driver rather than the Generic ones it is finding?

Note: I have tried the DPInst utility, the SetupCopyOEMInf function and pnputil.exe.  All methods "appear" to work (ie: no error messages), but Windows still grabs the generic driver first, no matter what.

I realize my understanding of drivers may be flawed.  I'm trying this on a Windows 7 x64 architecture, but I would like it to work universally.

Comment: Hey paul, did you manage to figure out something yet? I'm encountering the same situation right now and not sure how to have Windows detect the right device nor set it up through a python script.

Comment: I did not (at least not completely).  I made an installer using the DPInst utility.  Windows still refused to use the drivers initially, so it would install some generic driver first.  I managed to automate the process enough so that the installer (made using InnoSetup) would "update" the generic driver after it had been installed.  All in, a very frustrating process as it should have been a lot easier.

Comment: Dang well that's unfortunate. Luckily there are alternative paths to my solution for my situation so I guess I'm going to take one of those. Definitely seems like it should be easier...